# Rational points in homogeneous spaces

Tags: polynomials

I have some homogeneous spaces and I have to determine whether there are no rational points, or else exhibit one on them. The equations are the following (we need $(z_1,z_2,z_3)\in \mathbb{Q}^{\ast}\times\mathbb{Q}^{\ast}\times\mathbb{Q}^{\ast}$)

$$
2z_1^2-z_2^2=18,\quad z_1^2-z_3^2=17\\
z_1^2-2z_2=18,\quad z_1^2-2z_3^2=34\\
17z_1^2-z_2^2=18,\quad z_1^2-z_3^2=2\\
17z_1^2-z_2^2=9,\quad z_1^2-2z_3^2=1
$$

The way I was working so far on the other spaces was just by using mod arguments to show there can't be a solution in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for some $p$, but these methods dont seem to extend to these four remaining cases. Hopefully someone can give me some hints about how to do something with them?

Also, is there functionality in MAGMA or Mathematica for checking such a thing?

Comment: I found the point $(9,12,8)$ on the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the MAGMA function *HasRationalPoint($C$)* where $C$ is a conic, I was able to find points on all of them! Yay! If anyone is interested, here are the points: $(9,12,8)$, $(6,3,1)$, $(3/2,9/2,1/2)$, $(3,12,2)$.